# Как вывести в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел решить задачу, вышло правильно, но не так как надо. Задача:

> Выведите все числа на отрезке от a до b, дающие остаток c при делении на d. Если таких чисел не существует, то ничего выводить не нужно. Input: 2 5 0 2. В Output: 2 4.

В общем, вот мой код:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
sum = 0
for i in range(a,b+1):
   if i%d == c:
       print(i)
```

В выводе у меня вышло 2 и на другой строке 4, а должно быть чтобы 2 и 4 были в одной строке и с пробелом.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите print'у в качестве конца строки пробел (вместо перевода строки).

```
for i in range(a,b+1):
   if i%d == c:
       print(i, end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: а что это такое за end=" " и почему в конце print()? А так все правильно

Comment: end=" " - это указание print'у в качестве конца строки выводить пробел (вместо перевода строки). А в конце обычный print() чтобы таки вывести перевод строки.

Answer (score 0):

вам вот это нужно?

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())

print(*[i for i in range(a, b+1) if i % d == c])
```

тут ввод и вывод будет в 1 строку