# Как вывести print с циклом for _ in range() в одну строку?

Tags: python

есть программа

```
for k in range(1, 11):
    print(k)
```

надо что бы она вывела все цифра не по одной в каждой строке, а все цифры в одной по порядку

Comment: `print(*range(1, 11))` зачем здесь цикл вообще

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1353892/193892 - пойдет? print(k, end=" ")

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести в одну строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353889/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2):

```
for k in range(1, 11):
    print(k, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь все просто: можно использовать `*`

```py
print(*range(1, 11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий ответ от **@Рома Тютин** был верным, только небольшой недочёт с отступами .

```
mas = []  # создаем список
for k in range(1, 11): # цикл
    mas.append(k)  # добавить значение в список
print(mas)
```

Выход в консоли:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Поставьте `Print` **после** цикла. Задача полностью выполняется. Если требуется что-то другое, уточните/дополните свой вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

```
mas = []  # массив

for k in range(1, 11): # цикл
    mas.append(k)  # добавить цикл к массиву
    print(list(mas))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]