# Как вывести список простых чисел в одну строку сразу после "Простые числа от 1 до 50: "?

Tags: python, строки, вывод

```
import random
n = random.randint(1,100)
print('Случайное число:', n)
print('Простые числа от 1 до %d:' %n)
num = 2
count = 0
while num <= n:
    i = 2
    while num % i:
        i += 1
    if i == num:
        print(num, end=' ')
        count += 1
    num += 1
print('\nВсего %d простых чисел' %count)
```

*Результат:*

Случайное число: 50

Простые числа от 1 до 50:

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47

Всего 15 простых чисел

Comment: Так вы же выводите в одну строчку - в чём тогда проблема?

Comment: Нет, сейчас выводит в две строки.

Comment: @MBo Я так понял автора вопроса беспокоит та строка, что идёт до самих простых чисел )

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, теперь понятно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод в одну строку из разных print в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240814/); [Как вывести в одну строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353889/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Точно так же, как вы это делаете с выводом собственно самих простых чисел - указать `print` не переводить строку с помощью параметра `end`:

```py
print('Простые числа от 1 до %d:' %n, end=' ')
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

В данном случае заменяем перевод строки на пробел. А можно заменять и на пустой символ, например.

И лучше используйте современное форматирование через f-строки:

```py
print(f'Простые числа от 1 до {n}:', end=' ')
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Очень помогли~

Comment: @tana Вместо "спасибо", вы могли бы [принять данный ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) использая галочку слева.

Comment: вот как! спасибо